# How do I make my Heroku app available to see for others who have the link?

Tags: github, heroku, deployment, production, heroku-cli

So I deployed my first app, I am able to use it on my computer, but when I typed in the address on my phone or sent it to my friends they say it is just a blank page. How can I make it so others could see my app? Could find any answers, I am doing this for my portfolio, also i deployed using Github method.

Comment: Can you give us the address you're using, so we can take a look?

Answer (score 0):

So I made a mistake, it was actually delivering to users, but and the background color was showing, but React was not rendering because of some development-only script, had to do a function that would detect if app is in production or development and therefore apply the script or not.